# Why prediction of a predicted variable from a discriminant analysis is imperfect

Tags: regression, discriminant-analysis

I am puzzled by something I found using Linear Discriminant Analysis. Here is the problem - I first ran the Discriminant analysis using 20 or so independent variables to predict 5 segments. Among the outputs, I asked for the Predicted Segments, which are the same as the original segments for around 80% of the cases. Then I ran again the Discriminant Analysis with the same independent variables, but now trying to predict the Predicted Segments. I was expecting I would get 100% of correct classification rate, but that did not happen and I am not sure why. It seems to me that if the Discriminant Analysis cannot predict with 100% accuracy it own predicted segments then somehow it is not a optimum procedure since a rule exist that will get 100% accuracy. I am missing something?

Note - This situation seems to be similar to that in Linear Regression Analysis. If you fit the model $y = a + bX + \text{error}$ and use the estimated equation with the same data you will get $\hat{y}$ [$= \hat{a} + \hat{b}X$]. Now if you estimate the model $\hat{y} = \hat{a} + \hat{b}X + \text{error}$, you will find the same $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ as before, no error, and R2 = 100% (perfect fit). I though this would also happen with Linear Discriminant Analysis, but it does not.

Note 2 - I run this test with Discriminant Analysis in SPSS.

Comment: I am not sure why you feel that in regression you will get R2 = 1 if you try to predict the predicted variable. Can you clarify?

Comment: You could improve clarity in your question. Note that A (good) classification rule may make classification errors in the learning set, this is sometime a clue to avoide overfitting.

Comment: I think it is a good question; if I haven't known what I know I would thought the same.

Comment: @Srikant Because the RSS would vanish in this case, attached is a toy example: http://gist.github.com/547494 (I did not investigate the DA results though).

Comment: I also don't get how you get perfect fit with a line -- what if your points don't lie on any line?

Comment: I understand your question, and I share your conundrum.  I would think that any method to estimate something would be able to replicate its exact estimates if the latter are used as the dependent variable.  The method you use has its own constraints (linear relationships, normal distribution, or whatever).  But, the estimates by definition reflect the constraints of the method you use.  So, you should replicate the estimates exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite normal in case of machine learning -- it does not need to be optimal, it must be general.

Comment: To get the behavior you wanted, try using a simple CART.

Answer (score 1):

I am having troubling following your reasoning, but here are some things you should consider.

Generally, the harder you fit a model to your training data, the worse the model will perform on independent validation data sets. By over-fitting the model to the training set, you risk capturing predictor-response relationships that are particular to the training set you are using. These relationships are likely due to random chance. When building a model for classification, you want to only capture the predictor-response relationships that are common to all training sets. This is requires careful selection of the right size model (big enough to capture the true predictor-response relationship, small enough to not to overfit to your particular training set.)

Also, the fact that a linear regression gives an R^2 of 1 doesn't mean much. For example, I can generate a 101 X 100 matrix of N(0,1) observations, take the first column to be the "response", and the other 100 columns to be "predictors." This will give me an R^2 value of 1, even though the "response" and "predictors" are independent (assuming the rows/columns are linearly independent, which they will be with probability 1 if they are all N(0,1) observations.)  So in your n=5 observation, p=20 predictor case, you can choose any 5 predictors and get a perfect fit. R^2 is generally a pretty poor model assessment metric.

Also, unless you are certain the conditional distribution of the predictors is multivariate normal and that the predictors have a common covariance matrix, LDA may not be the best choice here. There are several better nonparametric/semiparametric methods available.

Maybe you can clarify your post a little bit to get a better response.